# Modelica: Is there a possibility to keep old default values in model in case of changed or deleted values in a newer library version?

Tags: modelica, dymola

Developing a model library in modelica we decided to change and delete some default values. At the moment I'm writing the **conversion script** to make sure that there are no problems updating the library while using it in another model.
Is there a possibility to **keep old default values in case of deleted or changed and renamed values** in a newer library version?

I'm aware of the possibility to keep the model values given in the model using the library with convertElement/ convertModifiers.

### Example:

Old version of the model in the library exampleLib:

```
model modelLib  
  parameter Real exampleVal = 2;  
end modelLib;
```

New version of the model in the library exampleLib:

```
model modelLib  
  parameter Real exampleValNew;  
end modelLib;
```

If the value would be given in 'exampleModel' with

```
model exampleModel
 exampleLib.modelLib exampleLibTest(exampleVal = 4)
end exampleModel;
```

a conversion script like

```
convertModifiers("exampleLib.modelLib", {"exampleVal"}, {"exampleValNew=%exampleVal%"});
```

would make sure that the parameter in exampleModel would be kept.

Is there any possibility to keep the default if there is no value given in 'exampleModel'?
In this case the code of the model using the library would be:

```
 model exampleModel  
   exampleLib.modelLib exampleLibTest;  
 end exampleModel;
```

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: It sounds to me like you need no conversion at all!? Can't you just remove the convertModifiers command, so your exampleVal modifiers will not be touched?

Comment: No, I tried to remove the command. Than there is no value given for exampleVal in exampleModel anymore.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases the following might also be an option.

It's a completely different solution as it keeps the default value in the library - but in a different way. That is done by having the following in the new library:

```
model modelLib  
  parameter Real exampleValNew(start=2);  
end modelLib;
```

Your old models that don't specify a value will run, but generate a warning.

Answer (score 1):

To rename a parameter or a variable without touching any of its modifiers use

```
convertElement("exampleLib.modelLib", "exampleVal", "exampleValNew");
```

Comment: Thank you, but then the new default value is used, isn't it? Imagine using the model library without setting the parameters in your model. Thus the default value of the library is used. Now we remove the default and rename the parameter in the library. If I use convertElement the parameter is renamed but not set to the old default. But in case of using the library in an old model without setting a default we want the old default value to be set in exampleModel.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with:

```
convertModifiers("exampleLib.modelLib", fill("",0), {"exampleValNew=2"});
```